# git: who pushed in post-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

How do I determine who pushed to the repository?

I.e. Somebody does `git push origin master` and in the post-receive hook on the `origin` repo I need to use the name or e-mail of Somebody.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using the SSH protocol to push changes to the server, with each user having their own account on the server, then your script should be running as the user who's doing the push. So, you should be able to use [`whoami`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/whoami1.html) or [`id -un`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/id1.html) to get the username of the person doing the push.

If you are not using this setup, the best way to keep track of who is pushing is probably using [Gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), a powerful Git authentication and authorization system. In Gitolite, you can use the [`update.secondary` and `post-update.secondary` hooks](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/hooks.html), which will have the `GL_USER` environment variable set to the current Gitolite user.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about those hooks.

Comment: The links to the hooks are now broken.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh Link should be fixed now.

Comment: +1 $GL_USER worked even in pre-receive (I have gitolite setup).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Git is meant to manage that kind of access control.

That is why you have ssh-based wrappers like [gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=blob;f=README.rst;hb=master) or [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) that will provide the adequate authentication level you are after.

Comment: I'm already using `gitolite` for access control. I just need the information for notifier script.

Comment: @takeshin... well, if I had known that, see Brian's answer (+1) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell that using Git. If you use SSH to push, then you can use SSH to get the username, if you use a user-management frontend such as gitolite, you can use *that* to get the username, if you use HTTP with authentication, you can use your webserver to get the username, but the Git networking protocols do not transmit any usernames.