# How to prevent commit to certain branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

We have many git repositories,  All repositories have a main branch named main_branch, e.g. The main_branch branch is the development base, I only want to update it at certain time. For everyday development, I hope everybody to create a new branch,  named develop_branch, e.g, and commit  their modifications to this develop_branch.

Are there some git configurations that can prevent commit to master_branch?  I hope these configurations can be easily shared among team members. Also, I expect the prevention can be disabled, e.g, by set environment variables, when I need to update main_branch.

Comment: If you host using something like BitBucket then the answer is yes.  You can configure your `master` branch so that certain users cannot push directly to it.  Instead, these users can create a pull request which must be reviewed and approved by an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Git itself does not have such feature, but many Git hosting solutions provide the feature. For example, GitLab and GitHub both have "protected branch" feature, which makes it possible to deny pushes to certain branches.

More info on GitHub here: https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/

And for GitLab: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/protected_branches.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible to reliably prevent developers from modifying the branch at their workstations, but you can prevent them from pushing to that branch on your server, with use of [update or pre-receive hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html). Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762012/git-who-pushed) for a way to identify the user from inside hook.